# 'TEXT()'. Expected Number, Date, DateTime, Picklist, received Lookup(User)

Tags: formula, lookup, salesforce-id

I'm trying to create a field on the Case object that references a user lookup field on the Account object.

Using this:

```
Account.Customer_Success_Rep__c
```

Returns the correct user, but shows the Salesforce ID and I'd like the name.

My problem is that this:

```
TEXT(Account.Customer_Success_Rep__c)
```

Gives me this error:

```
Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'TEXT()'. Expected Number, Date, DateTime, Picklist, received Lookup(User)
```

Why isn't this working? How can I get the text of the field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd want to use the relationship instead:

```
Account.Customer_Success_Rep__r.FirstName & " " &
Account.Customer_Success_Rep__r.LastName
```

TEXT is specifically for converting numbers, dates, and the like to strings so you can manipulate them, not for converting ID values to a label of some sort.

A field where you can select a user with the magnifying glass is not a "picklist", it is a "lookup" field.

Comment: Concatenating first name with first name?

Comment: @AdrianLarson lol, It's been a long, long morning.

Answer (score 2):

Customer_Success_Rep__c field is a lookup field, you should be accessing some other field in that lookup. Try making your formula `Account.Customer_Success_Rep__r.FirstName` (or other field if `FirstName` is not what you want).

If you access the Customer_Success_Rep__c it returns the ID of the lookup object, but accessing as Customer_Success_Rep__r (with **r**), you get access to its fields.

You can also use the "Insert Field" helper when defining the formula instead of typing it.